# Mac: How to back up XCode4 Installer to Network Drive

Tags: macos, xcode

I have a MBP with very limited space because I am using an SSD. I downloaded XCode4 (4.5GB) from the appStore and installed it. I want to copy my XCode4 installer to my WHS network shared drive. However when I try to do this it says:

> One or more items can't be copied to
>   "Mac Apps" because you don't have
>   permissions to read them. Do you want
>   to copy the items you are allowed to
>   read?"

There is only 1 file, so it fails to copy anything. This doesn't happen for other files I move from my Mac to WHS and I can read, write, and modify to my WHS just fine.

I thought maybe to zip it first, but when I try to Compress the file it says:

> "The Operation Can't be completed
>   because you don't have permissions to
>   access ".changedIcons".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the Applications/Utilities folder, run the Disk Utility App. Select the main hard drive and repair permissions. Once that completes, ensure the xcode dmg is dismounted and try thr copy operation again.

Comment: Its a no go. Its weird with this file if I move it to a different folder on the harddrive or to the trash it requires me verify my credentials. 

Maybe Apple doesn't want you backing up the installs from the appStore. This is all their support site says. 

"How do I back up my purchases?

We recommend backing up the contents of your Mac regularly, including photos, purchased movies, TV shows, and apps, to ensure that you can easily recover them in the event of a loss. If you need to recover a previously purchased app from the Mac App Store, you can redownload it if it is still available."

Comment: I downloaded the xcode4 dmg image and just copied it to my USB drive. Then I deleted it no problem. How long ago did you swap the original drive with the SSD you're running? It sounds like a permissions issue to me, but I could be wrong. When all else fails, I drop to the command line... Could be worth a try.

Comment: Just got the MBP and just swapped in the SSD and did a clean install. Did you get xcode4 from the appstore or from Apple Developer program?

Comment: I downloaded it from the web site. Frankly, I don't trust the app software and *rarely* run it.

Comment: Yeah I think its a DRM thing. Most Appstore programs install directly when you buy them. XCode is an exception case as it just downloads an installer and you have to install it. I think Apple put some special permissions on the installer to prevent you from sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/Applications/Install\ Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/.changedIcons` has no permissions set.  Try changing the permission to read only via a Terminal window like so:

```
sudo chmod 444 /Applications/Install\ Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/.changedIcons
```

Then try your backup.  This worked for me when burning Xcode to a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

The error does sound odd, but putting it aside, if the underlying filesystem of your WHS is Fat32, then it's got a 4GB file size limit, meaning your 4.5GB XCode file won't be allowed there.